# Trying to import flurry analytics into my app delegate... any suggestions?

Tags: ios, api, analytics, flurry

When I try to add to the code, I receive semantic and parse issues. Does anybody know what the proper way I could add this to my app?

The first set of code is my original code without the analytics, the next set of code is what the told me to put in my app. Can anybody suggest a set of code I could try?

Original Code

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

myWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: frame];

if (myWindow)
{
    UIImageView *newView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];

    if (newView)
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Launch.png"];

        if (image)
        {
            [newView setImage: image];
        }

        [newView setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];

        UIGestureRecognizer *newRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(refresh)];

        if (newRecognizer)
        {
            [newView addGestureRecognizer: newRecognizer];

            [newRecognizer release];
        }

        [myWindow addSubview: newView];

        [newView release];
    }

    [myWindow makeKeyAndVisible];

    myModel = [[NBSHomeModel alloc] init];

    [myModel setDelegate: self];

    [myModel reload];
}

return YES;
}
```

Here is the code from Flurry's instructions

```
#import "Flurry.h"
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{
 [Flurry startSession:@"YOUR_API_KEY"];
 //your code
}
```

Comment: Have you configured the flurry library files with your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create Account in Flurry and then you have id of your flurry **API_KEY** right.

Now i just giving One Zip file downlode from bellow link:-

http://www.sendspace.com/file/y9nqcl

In this Zip you have Two folder

- **FlurryAnalytics**
- **FlurryAppCircle**

add Both into your Project.

Now in your AppDelegate.m Import this `#import "FlurryAnalytics.h"`

and in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [FlurryAnalytics startSession:@"YOR_API_KEY"];

}
```

**NOTE:-** its App Analysis reflecting in flurry site may be take's some time to display graph

Comment: Thank you so much your a lifesaver

Comment: hey can you upload that file for me again? I promise to take better care of it this time around haha

Comment: this file found from flurry site check there and download from there flurry provide ios sdk file i download from there.  hahaha